# How to filter a GAE query?

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-datastore

I'm trying to save two records and then get the 2nd one. The issue is that the filter doesn't seem to work. Although I filter by Name ("Andrew W") I always get "Joe Citizen". The counter also indicates 2 records when it should be just one. This drives me crazy. See the full code below.
The result prints `counter 2 e2 {"Joe Citizen" "Manager" "2015-03-24 09:08:58.363929 +0000 UTC" ""}`

```
package main
import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
    "net/http"

    "google.golang.org/appengine"
    "google.golang.org/appengine/datastore"
)


type Employee struct {
    Name     string
    Role     string
    HireDate time.Time
    Account  string
}
func init(){

    http.HandleFunc("/", handle)
}
func handle(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    c := appengine.NewContext(r)

    e1 := Employee{
        Name:     "Joe Citizen",
        Role:     "Manager",
        HireDate: time.Now(),
    }

    _, err := datastore.Put(c, datastore.NewKey(c, "employee", "", 0, nil), &e1)
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
    panic(err)
        return
    }
    e1.Name = "Andrew W"

    _, err = datastore.Put(c, datastore.NewKey(c, "employee", "", 0, nil), &e1)
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
    panic(err)
        return
    }

    var e2 Employee
    q :=  datastore.NewQuery("employee")
    q.Filter("Name =", "Andrew W")
    cnt, err  := q.Count(c)
    if err !=nil{
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
        panic(err)
        return
    }
    for t := q.Run(c); ; {  
        if _, err := t.Next(&e2); err != nil {
             http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
            panic(err)
            return
        }
        break
    }   
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "counter %v e2 %q", cnt, e2)
}
```

Comment: Almost certainly because of eventual consistency.

Comment: I doubt that. The filters should filter the data anyway. Also the eventual consistency query has its own api https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/appengine/datastore#Query.EventualConsistency

Comment: @Theuserwithnohat The link you provided only applies when you use ancestor queries, which you don't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The (first) problem is this:

```
q :=  datastore.NewQuery("employee")
q.Filter("Name =", "Andrew W")
```

[`Query.Filter()`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/datastore/reference#Query.Filter) returns a derivative query with the filter you specified included. You have to store the return value and use it ongoing:

```
q := datastore.NewQuery("employee")
q = q.Filter("Name =", "Andrew W")
```

Or just one line:

```
q := datastore.NewQuery("employee").Filter("Name =", "Andrew W")
```

Note: Without this the query you execute would have no filters and therefore would return all previously saved entities of the kind `"employee"`, where `"Joe Citizen"` might be the first one which you see printed.

For the first run you will most likely see 0 results. Note that since you don't use Ancestor queries, **eventual consistency applies**. The development SDK simulates the High replication datastore with its eventual consistency, and therefore the query following the `Put()` operations will not see the results.

If you put a small `time.Sleep()` before proceeding with the query, you will see the results you expect:

```
time.Sleep(time.Second)

var e2 Employee
q := datastore.NewQuery("employee").Filter("Name=", "Andrew W")
// Rest of your code...
```

Also note that running your code in the SDK you can simulate **strong consistency** by creating your context like this:

```
c, err := aetest.NewContext(&aetest.Options{StronglyConsistentDatastore: true})
```

But of course this is for testing purposes only, you can't do this in production.

If you want strongly consistent results, specify an ancestor key when creating the key, and use [ancestor queries](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/datastore/queries#Go_Ancestor_queries). An ancestor key is only required if you want strongly consistent results. If you're fine with a few seconds delay for the results to show up, you don't have to. Also note that the ancestor key does not have to be the key of an existing entity, it's just semantics. You can create any fictional key. Using the same (fictional) key to multiple entities will put them into the same entity group and ancestor queries on this group will be strongly consistent.

Often the ancestor key is an existing key, usually derived from the current user or account, because that can be created/computed easily and it holds/stores some additional information, but as noted above, it doesn't have to be.

Comment: I'm not sure what ancestor key to use because there is no ancestor. "employee" is the root entity. Maybe I'm missing something but why does the API return the query pointer instead to update it? It doesn't look wise to me, at least not for the most common use cases.

Comment: @Theuserwithnohat It's a design decision. This way `Query` can be immutable, can be shared and reused.

Comment: @Theuserwithnohat An ancestor key is only required if you want strongly consistent results. If you're fine with a few seconds delay for the results to show up, you don't have to. Also note that the ancestor key does not have to be the key of an existing entity, it's just semantics. You can create any fictional key. Using the same (fictional) key to multiple entities will put them into the same entity group and ancestor queries on this group will be strongly consistent.

Comment: So the ancestor is basically a kind lock.

Comment: @Theuserwithnohat Not a kind, group. Multiple entities of the same kind can have different parents (or none at all), and entities from multiple kinds can have the same parent.

Comment: Note that, at this time, NewContext does not take any parameters. NewInstance does, at which point you're dealing with development-server instance-creation semantics rather than merely a new-context call.

Comment: Also note that writes to any given entity group are serialized and are limited to about 1 per SECOND, per entity group.  So in practice you need to have a separate entity group for each (human) user that is updated at most once per page.  If you need cross-user strongly consistent transactions, you are out of luck.